# McDonnell-Douglas 16-bit microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessor

I've been working on the [NatSemi PACE article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Semiconductor_PACE) and I'm trying to track down a bit of trivia... someone inserted a statement:

> McDonnell Douglas produced a classified military 16-bit processor called the "Actron" around 1973

I did a bit of googling... Actron Industries was a company in the 1960s that McD purchased. The hits I found suggest they worked on optical systems and sensors, and there's a reference or two to data processing of those images, but from the 1980s.

I suppose that Actron might have built a CPU, but that seems unlikely. It's also possible they just called it that, or even more likely that it was used in an Actron *product* and the name got confused.

In any event, does anyone know of a McD processor?

Comment: That footnote has a *[citation needed]* on it.  Whoever wrote it may have been thinking of the [CADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Air_Data_Computer).

Comment: Yeah, but CADC was Garrett, 20-bit, and multi-chip. And I put the cite needed for just this reason.

Comment: See some mention of Actron and the Nitron Division of McDonnell Douglas working on a microprocessor but that seems to be mid-late 70's.  (search Google Books for `Actron processor`).

Comment: Air University Review 1973 - Volume 26 - Page 24 has an image + mention: https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Air_University_Review/KE87AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=actron%20microprocessor&pg=RA5-PA24&printsec=frontcover&bsq=actron%20microprocessor

Comment: Actron AM1608 microprocessor reference in Proceedings of the American Society of Photogrammetry Fall Technical Meeting 1975. Very small snippet shown in Google books search however. (search on `Actron AM1 608 microprocessor`)

Comment: I can't answer, it's classified

Comment: So the key is "AM1608", which turns up *some* references. It seems it post-dates the PACE, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here is what I have so far:

Based on Brian's reference, it appears that the design was originally fabbed as a three-chip set. The caption in the magazine speaks of "other chips are the arithmetic unit and the memory..." which *strongly* suggests this is a three-chip unit similar in construction to the original IMP-16, where instruction decode on one chip and ALU on another - the last might be ROM or microcode.

Also note the language in the caption, "the ACTRON microprocessor set called UDAM", which further suggests this is a multi-chip design, and that it wasn't called "the" Actron, but is simply a product *from* Actron. I wonder if the claim that this was called "the Actron" comes literally from this caption?

It appears they did indeed make a single-chip version of this, the AM1608. This definitely comes from a later date, as several references speak of McD "talking to" potential customers in the late 1975 time frame. The only references that mention actually *using* the design all post-date that era.

As such I have removed the claim from the PACE article, it appears very safe to conclude it remains the first single-chip 16-bit general purpose CPU design.